# How to convert a Node js based website to a mobile app?

Tags: node.js, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I have a node js based web app also using HTML CSS and Javascript. I want to convert it into a mobile app compatible with both android and ios. What is the best approach for this? Can I use cordova to convert to a mobile app?

Comment: I'm using a similar structure using ios: `Webkit`, android: `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks @Jain Can you give me some good how to links

Comment: I make it referenced to [WKWebView Overview - webView.load(myRequest)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) and [WebView loadUrl()](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview).